# How to draw one cell in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can I draw one cell in text line? Something like this:

[image: One Cell]

Comment: That looks like an ordinary rectangle. Why don't you create a `Chunk` with non-breaking space characters and draw a rectangle using a generic tag event? Another option would be to create a `PdfTemplate` with a rectangle and then add the `PdfTemplate` as an `Image` (vector format). There are really many different ways to achieve what you want. What have you tried?

Comment: I draw table with 3 columns 1 and 3 with no border.

Comment: That's another valid option. Well done!